# Disable welcome email for a new Microsoft 365 group immediately

Tags: powershell, office365, microsoft365

After creating a new Microsoft 365 group and disabling the welcome email for its members with powershell:

`Set-UnifiedGroup $group_name -UnifiedGroupWelcomeMessageEnabled:$false`

I added members to this group and they still got the welcome email. This shows there is some delay on Microsoft side for the changes to get propagated. I verified that this happens with 250 seconds delay (since config update to members addition). Disable of welcome email is rendered useless due to this delay on MS side.

I am looking for a way to create new Microsoft 365 group that has welcome email disabled immediately i.e. new users added immediately should not get the welcome email.

Is there a way to create new Microsoft 365 group programmatically (via api or powershell) with welcome email disabled? I could not find any leads on the same.

Comment: Just tested this out on my tenant. While I did not see such a long delay as you, I too saw a delay as long as 30 seconds before the value for `WelcomeMessageEnabled` was effective.I also saw it go into effect as quickly as five seconds, so there is definitely some variability.As far as I can tell, there's no way to make a group with that setting disabled as part of the creation. I'm not sure there's anything that can be done other than adding a delay to your process/script to account for the problem.

Comment: i would do anything to get these to never ever send

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the New-UnifiedGroup cmdlet used to have something like what you are looking for:

-SuppressWarmupMessage
This parameter has been deprecated and is no longer used.

Sounds like the only way to do this would be to pre-create the groups several hours in advance so that the settings take effect.